# Getting Distinct Count using SQL?

Tags: sql, delphi, interbase

Simple SQL for you SQL experts.

I have two fields (AccountNo, CheckNo). There can be more than 1 checkno that has the same value. It will have the same AccountNo. I would like a listing from mytable displaying AccountNo and CheckNo, as was as the count of how many times it exists.

```
Select Distinct AccountNo, CheckNo, Count(Distinct AccountNo, CheckNo) as Total
from MyTable
```

Comment: Select Distinct AccountNo, CheckNo, Count(1) as Total from MyTable GROUP BY AccountNo, CheckNo ???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are after is `GROUP BY`

```
Select AccountNo, CheckNo, Count(*) as Total
from MyTable
group by AccountNo, CheckNo
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select AccountNo, CheckNo, Count(*) as Total
from MyTable
group by AccountNo, CheckNo
```

Comment: `Count(AccountNo, CheckNo)` => invalid syntax. Now that it is edited it is exactly the same as my answer, even down to 3-lining it.

Comment: @cyberkiwi: was edited before you commented. I saved by mistake. As for being the same, it isn't rocket science...